# How introduce anchor links when fetching a url from SQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

This is the PHP script and I can load my data in database but elements in the Link row seems not clickable .so that I redirect the user.
My attempt was to add anchor() tags similar to table definition but its still inactive.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accident_log");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Link</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<a><td>" . $row['Link'] . "</td></a>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<td><a href='" . $row['Link'] . "'></a></td>";` try this

Comment: @RamondeVries You should also provide the text for the link otherwise it will show as blank.

Comment: @Dharman that's right, UPDATE: `echo "<td><a href='" . $row['Link'] . "'>" . $row['Link'] . "</a></td>";`

Comment: As a side note, you are not checking for mysqli errors properly. You need to enable exceptions. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @RamondeVries Rather than posting possible answers in comments, an answer would be more fitting, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i understand, but i cannot run his code myself, therefor i'm not 100% sure my solution works, in that case. I'd rather not post it as an anwser

Comment: @RamondeVries Post is as a community wiki and then everyone can chip in and edit to make it better. Comments are only for asking for clarifications.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Learn here if you do not know https://www.w3schools.com

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $row['link'] . '">' . $row['link'] . '</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="' . $row['link'] . '" style="background: #09f; color: #fff; padding: 10px 20px;">' . $row['link'] . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Do not suggest w3schools.com for learning PHP. They are know to provide really bad examples. If you want to teach something be kind and explain your answer to the OP. An answer which just tells them to learn something from some website is low quality and might get downvoted.

Comment: Examples are excellent, especially for beginners. I don't collect your points. I always answer the question from the new user.